# cakephp issue on local computer

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I took over the administration of a cakephp site about 6 months ago, the site runs `cakephp v2.0.5` on an apache server running `PHP 5.3.27`

I am using WAMP with the only difference being the version of `PHP 5.3.13`

The problem i get is this error which appears a number of time on the home page -

`Warning (512): Method UiHelper::parse does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 191]`

this is the code

```
public function __call($method, $params) {
    trigger_error(__d('cake_dev', 'Method %1$s::%2$s does not exist', get_class($this), $method), E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on the error as I cannot find anything on the web?

Cheers
David

Comment: can you paste the code from the `PagesController`, or the controller/action you are getting this error on?

Comment: Hi David, I am just wondering whether you've resolved this issue? If you have can you shed some light thanks!

Comment: Hi Danlee, unfortunately no, and as it happens I no longer look after that client